# Regex para separar uma string

Tags: javascript

Galera
Eu preciso separar um pedaço de uma string para colocar como resultado de uma classe especifica.

Eu tenho o seguinte retorno

```
02/10/2017 a 05/10/2017 em São Paulo - Papercut MF Técnico Presencial (28 hrs) - Vagas disponíveis
```

Precisava de algum regex para separar no texto na primeira ocorrência do a,sempre na primeira ocorrência de a,  que fica entre as datas.

Desde já agradeço

Comment: Não podes usar simplesmente um substring ?

Comment: Não, o retorno varia de tamanho, preciso da primeira ocorrência do a mesmo

Comment: Isso dá uma idéia de como sugeri:
var textoDoRetorno = "02/10/2017 a 05/10/2017 em São Paulo - Papercut MF Técnico Presencial (28 hrs) - Vagas disponíveis";

 
console.log("PRIMEIRA OCORRENCIA :"+textoDoRetorno.substring(0, textoDoRetorno.indexOf("A")));

O retorno, você quer algum indice da letra "A" ou o conteudo até a primeira ocorrencia ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a seguinte expressão regular:

```
/([0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}) a ([0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4})/g
```

Esta expressão irá procurar 2 números, seguidos de barra, seguido de mais 2 números, seguido de barra novamente e logo após, mais 4 números. Após isso procurará a `String` `a` e a mesma combinação.

```js
var texto = "02/10/2017 a 05/10/2017 em São Paulo - Papercut MF Técnico Presencial (28 hrs) - Vagas disponíveis";

console.log(separar(texto));

function separar(texto) {
  var regex = /([0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}) a ([0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4})/g;
  var resultado = [];
  var combinacao = regex.exec(texto);
  
  resultado.push(combinacao[1]);
  resultado.push(combinacao[2]);
  
  return resultado;
}
```

Comment: Cara, muito bom mesmo. valeu

Answer (score 1):

Eu entendi que você quer pegar uma parte de uma string então...

Você pode transformar a string num array separando os elementos por espaços:

```
var teste = "02/10/2017 a 05/10/2017";
var arrayTeste = teste.split(' ');
```

Isso vai retornar uma array com 3 elementos:

0- 02/10/2017

1- a

2- 05/10/2017

Você pode pegar eles separadamente:

```
arrayTeste[0];
arrayTeste[1];
arrayTeste[2];
```

Se quiser ainda pode usar o split('/') para separar o dia, mes e ano

Observações:
O primeiro elemento tem a posição 0, o segundo a posição 1 assim por diante

Os elementos não terão mais o caractere espaço ( ) porque o split apaga ele para separar os elementos do array

Recomendo que assista os vídeos do rodrigo branas -  https://www.youtube.com/user/rodrigobranas ele tem vídeos sobre js, angularjs e nodejs